# Where does the additional 1 proton cost of oxidative phosphorylation come from?

Tags: biochemistry

I've been quite confused by the source of the additional 1H+ cost right now. I know it costs the F1Fo-ATP synthase 3H+  to produce an ATP, and it is also stated that:

> ADP3−cytoplasm + ATP4−matrix → ADP3−matrix + ATP4−cytoplasm //
>   ADP/ATP exchange is energetically expensive: about 25% of the energy yielded from electron transfer by aerobic respiration, or one hydrogen ion, is consumed to regenerate the membrane potential that is tapped by ADP/ATP translocase.(*Wikipedia/ADP/ATP Translocase*)

So in some books I find out that they regard the net cost of producing an ATP as 4H+. Here is another statement:

> The phosphate carrier, which works in concert with ATP-ADP translocase, mediates the electroneutral exchange of H2PO4-for OH- (or, indistinguishably, the electroneutral symport of H2PO4- and H+). The combined action of these two transporters leads to the exchange of cytosolic ADP and Pi for matrix ATP at the cost of an influx of one H+. (*Berg JM, Tymoczko JL, Stryer L. Biochemistry. 5th edition. New York: W H Freeman; 2002. Section 18.5, Many Shuttles Allow Movement Across the Mitochondrial Membranes.*)

And my question comes here. Why do we not consider the effect of the process of ADP + Pi → ATP on the membrane potential? It also produces a net cost of 2e-. Putting these together, this will lead to 0, i.e. no additional net cost. Or should I only consider H+ but not e-?
(This might lead to another problem about H2PO4-'s breakup.)

Answer (score 3):

The energy required for the ATP production by ATP synthase is obtained from movement of ions (H<sup>+</sup> or in some cases Na<sup>+</sup>) downstream of their potential (proton motive force). I guess, there is no exact stoichiometric exchange as in case of ion pumps. The rotation of the motor is generated by the movement of protons through a channel. The H<sup>+</sup>/ATP ratio is estimated using biophysical/biochemical techniques.

[Brand and Lehninger (1977)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC431051/) estimated this ratio to be greater than 3.

[Turina et al. (2003)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC140756/) recalculated this ratio using constituted liposomes and their estimate is  3.9 ± 0.2.

This is an excerpt from a more recent study on chloroplast ATP synthase by [Hahn et al (2018)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.aat4318).

> The symmetry mismatch between the 14-fold Fo rotor and the
>   near-threefold F1 head means that the number of c subunits rotating
>   past subunit a to generate one ATP is not an integer. cF1Fo requires,
>   on average, 4.67 c subunits, or protons, to produce one ATP. The
>   nearest integral numbers of c subunits per step would be 4, 5, and 5,
>   equivalent to rotation angles of 103°, 129°, and 129°. Surprisingly
>   however, the three conformations are separated by rotations of 103°,
>   112°, and 145°, or 4, 4.4, and 5.6 c subunits (fig. S5C). This means
>   that the position of the c subunits relative to subunit a in the three
>   conformations differs.

The structure and efficiency of chloroplast ATP synthase may be a little different but what I want to emphasize is that there is no exact exchange of protons and ATP.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that the calculations are just estimated from experiments is a fair point. But actually it was some statements from pratice problems when I studied biochemistry that cause some ambiguity, for example the contradictory statements 'ATP/ADP tanslocase adds 1 net cost to ATP production' and 'Pi/H+ transfer adds one'. But I will bear in mind that they're all rough calculations. I really thought the F1Fo-ATP synthase was symmetric (regardless of the change in conformation) just like the honeycomb before I read your answer.